# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors by inspection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How can one find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix
$\begin{bmatrix}
6 & 6\\ 
 6& 6
\end{bmatrix}$ by simple inspection?

Comment: Hint: zero is one eigenvalue. (why?). Also: trace and determinant.

Answer (score 2):

- It is not full rank, so zero is an eigenvalue. It is not hard to check that $(1,-1)$ is an eigenvector.
- You can check directly that $(1,1)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $12$.
- Since the matrix is $2 \times 2$, these are all the eigenvalues and eigenvectors (up to scaling)

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of singular value decomposition:

\begin{align}\begin{bmatrix} 6 & 6\\ 6 & 6\end{bmatrix}&=6\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\\&=6\left(\sqrt{2}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}\right)\left(\sqrt{2}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}\right)
\\&=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}[12]\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix} \\&=
\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 12 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}\end{align}

We can read off the eigenvalues and the corresponding eigenvector.

Remark:

We can study a more general question of what is the eigenvalue and eigenvector of a square matrix of which each entries is identical, say $k$.

We can represent such as matrix as $A=kee^T$ wher $e \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the all one vector.

Multiply $A$ with $e$, we have $Ae=kee^Te=ken=(kn)e$, hence $kn$ is an eigenvalue with eigenvector $e$.

Clearly $e$ is a rank 1 matrix, hence nullity of $A$ would be $n-1$.

Let $e_i$ be the standard unit vector where the $i$-th position is $1$ and $0$ otherwise.
Let $j > 1$,
from RREF of $A$, we can see that $e_1-e_j$ are $n-1$ independent eigenvectors of $A$ with eigenvalue being $0$.